# Accessing properties in Serilog when not using destructuring

Tags: serilog

A project I'm working on currently ships logs to ElasticSearch, and along with the log message I'd like to include some additional metadata on a case by case basis using the following model:

```cs
log.Warning("Something went wrong", new
{
    EmailAddress = "example@example.com",
});
```

Initially I thought accessing these properties could be easily done via extending the sink (using `ILogEventSink.Emit(LogEvent logEvent);`) and writing them to the final log output. However I noticed that the properties are only populated when you destructure the log message.

Are there any ways of accessing the object passed in the aforementioned code example? Or alternative means of attaching metadata to your message without having to use destructuring within the log message?

Answer (score 0):

Not certain of your ask but:

```
log.ForContext("EmailAddress","example@example.com")
   .Warning("Something went wrong")
```

Will add an `EmailAddress` property to the captured set [and you'll see them rendered in `{Properties}` fields in message templates and [presumably] in the messages as shipped to ES].

I'm pretty sure the arg in your example will be ignored - holes in the message template get filled by args in order - any extras are ignored. (I guess, you can confirm or rule out my guess this by installing [Serilog Analyzer](https://github.com/Suchiman/SerilogAnalyzer) or reading the Serilog tests)